# Do I have to make lifelines for every class function passes for my Sequence diagrams?

Tags: java, uml, sequence-diagram

I am working on a Sequence diagram, but I am confused on how to show the following bit of sequence diagram.

I am trying to instantiate a variable by first calling a function to get the variable type. I already have made myMainObject. So that object exists and I understand I have to do a create on something when I instantiate it.

```
 myMainObject().getObjectController().getObject();
```

So does this mean I create ObjectController AND I also create Object lifelines?

```
 --------------
| myMainObject |
  ------------- 
       |
       |  getObjectcontroller()   -----------------
       | ----------------------->| ObjectController|
       |                          ------------------
       |                                  |         getObject()   ---------
       |                                  |--------------------->| Object  |
       |                                  |                       ---------
       |                                  |                           |
                                                                      |
```

Or is the following more than enough information? And let the programmer figure out on how to get the correct object.

```
  --------------------------
 | myMainObject: MainObject|
  ------------------------- 
           |
           |   myObject = getObject() ---------
           | ----------------------->| Object  |
           |                          ---------
           |                              |         
           |                              |
           |                              |                  
           |                              |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObjectController` doesn't call `Object`. *You* call both methods.

```
 -----
| You |
 -----
   |
   |  getObjectcontroller()   -------------
   | ----------------------> | MainObject |
   |                          -------------
   |        Objectcontroller        |
   | <----------------------------- |
   |                                |
   |
   |               getObject()                 ------------------
   | ---------------------------------------> | Objectcontroller |
   |                                           ------------------
   |                      Object                       |
   | <------------------------------------------------ |
   |                                                   |
```

Comment: Aaah Yes this is the way to go indeed. I do call both methods. Kinda silly of me. Thank you for your very quick answer.

Comment: That's the real answer! Please @deltu100 mark it as the correct answer.